# Fetch request does not accept body but requests.get does

Tags: reactjs, python-requests, fetch

I have an requests `GET` api that accepts a `body` in order to filter based on what is in body. Shown below, the logic is to get tasks of a specific cluster with `<cluster_id>`. `Django` is been used for backend. And I am integrating this with `React`.

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/v1/tasks"

payload={'cluster': <cluster_id>}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Token <user_token>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I am attempting the same using fetch in frontend, even though I clearly understand it isn't recommended to use a body in a GET request.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        cluster: this.state.cluster_id
    })
    }
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/v1/tasks`, options)
    const json = await response.json()
    return json
  }
```

I got an error that restricts using body in GET requests. How could I apply the logic in fetch without modify the rest api structure? Is it even possible, to use a body in a fetch GET request and retrieve data?

Comment: What's wrong with passing it as a query parameter?

Comment: `/tasks/<cluster_id>` is not a query param. Query params will look like this `/tasks?cluster=42`, which is how, in your case, your backend is expecting the data

Comment: Oh yes I meant, that way.  backend's logic does not work with that. backend uses `django`, so the logic uses `requests.data.get('cluster')` which works for other request types other than GET instead of `request.query_params['cluster]` which works for GET, would have definitely worked with query_params. to get the `cluster_id`. I think, this will have to be a backend modification, if there is no alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

GET doesn't support body in the request. Even if you pass it, it will be ignored.

You can use `URLSearchParams` to convert your params to query parameters to be sent along with the url.

`new URLSearchParams(params).toString()`

```
const params = { cluster: this.state.cluster_id };
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
};
const url = `http://localhost:8000/v1/tasks?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`
const response = await fetch(url, options)
```